# Foreach loop jumping one part of array writing in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Here is the problem, I am passing data through post method, I'm using for each variable mysqli real escape string, all good till then, when I am passing those in an array to write every single one in the database, is jumping one part of the array, exactly the $p2 => $pNr2, some ideas why?

[image]

```php
      $array = array($p1 => $pNr1, $p2 => $pNr2, $p3 => $pNr3, $p4 => $pNr4, $p5 => $pNr5, $p6 => $pNr6,
          $p7 => $pNr7, $p8 => $pNr8, $p9 => $pNr9, $p10 => $pNr10, $p11 => $pNr11, $p12 => $pNr12, $p13 => $pNr13, $p14 => $pNr14, $p15 => $pNr15);
       foreach ($array as $arr => $key) {
           $writePlayer = "UPDATE team1 SET nume = '$arr' WHERE playerNr = '$key';";
           mysqli_query($conn, $writePlayer);
       }
```

Comment: Use prepared statement.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks.

Comment: Same problem, @freeek even with prepared statement still skips one part of the array, the same one.

Comment: Post the code of generation all this `$p1 => $pNr` together with you prepared statement example, please.

Answer (score 0):

This includes many client-server round trips between mysql and php server. It can possibly lead to mysql not completing the update before receiving next one. You could use multiple statements to reduce this communication.

```
$writePlayer = '';   
foreach ($array as $arr => $key) {
       $writePlayer. = "UPDATE team1 SET nume = '$arr' WHERE playerNr = '$key';";
   }
mysqli_multi_query($conn, $writePlayer);
```

Of course, I would suggest using prepared statements.